# Meteor: How to Resubscribe After Database Updated by Third Party

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactive-programming

I have a node api that updates some of my data thus I lose reactivity and normally have ~5 second delay before data is reloaded. Is there a way to resubscribe (in iron router, or outside or iron router) after the node api returns success so I can update UI immediately?

Comment: Have you configured Meteor to use your mongodb's oplog? If you haven't already done so, it should solve your issue.

Comment: @Akshat I have not. Do you know of any good reading material on it, and at what level in the stack are these changes are done?

Comment: Here is Meteor's resource for enabling the oplog: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver  Without oplog enabled in production long polling can often take up to 10 seconds.